# Understanding the meaning of だからな in this line

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, usage

I am currently playing the Japanese version of Octopath Traveler. In one scene in particular, there are two characters in prison; one of them (a kid named Therion) has just been hit by the guard and put behind bars in the same cell as the other (an older guy named Cyrus).

Then the dialogue goes like this:

> Cyrus: よう、派手に殴られたな
>
> Therion: ...誰だ？
>
> Cyrus: お前と変わらねえよ 盗みをやって捕まったゴロツキさ
>
> Therion: ...お前もひどい顔だ
>
> Cyrus: 子供だろうが手加減なしだからな 躾ける親もいなけりゃ盗みも平気... そんな生意気な悪ガキの性根を
> 叩き直してやってるつもりなのさ

So there are a few things I don't understand. I don't quite get what だからな means in the last piece of dialogue. I've looked that expression up in this web page and it seems to me that it might mean something like "you know?".

Also, I don't get if Cyrus is talking about what the guards will do (something like "they won't hold back even if you are a kid" and "they will beat your bad attitude out of you"), or if he is talking about himself, as in he will be the one that will not hold back and will discipline Therion.

I will very much appreciate any help in unraveling the meaning of this last piece of dialogue.

Comment: Isn't the older guy [Darius](https://octopathtraveler.fandom.com/wiki/Darius)? [Cyrus](https://octopathtraveler.fandom.com/wiki/Cyrus_Albright) is a gentle scholar who doesn't speak like that.

Comment: だからな is the ordinary だから (which can be seen in any dictionary; in turn this is copula だ + conjunction から) + な as a sentence-ending particle (comparable to ね).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[な](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AA/#je-55709) in だからな does not add much in terms of meaning. Here it is 'weak assertion' or sort of 'surprise' (#4 in the linked j-e dictionary). A female character may say ...だから in the same scene.

だから itself is just *because*. In the context, ***because** they are equally harsh to children (you got beaten up)*. As a translation, *you know* may work more or less.

From the provided context, the final sentences seem to refer to the guard. It describes what the guards or their beating does.

First note that 躾ける親もいなけりゃ盗みも平気... describes kids like Therion and the phrase is referred to by そんな. So, forgetting that part for now, 子供だろうが手加減なしだからな そんな生意気な悪ガキの性根を 叩き直してやってるつもりなのさ means *"they won't hold back even if you are a kid" and "they will beat your bad attitude out of you"*, as you understand. The latter is more literally *they will beat your 性根(inner personality) of bad boys like that*. 性根を叩き直す means something like *to discipline a corrupt personality/mind*.